# How to add new column with content to WooCommerce product reviews table?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, review

I want to show a new column in WooCommerce product reviews. I tried to use below code to display new column But this code does not work.
How can I do this?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_reviews_table_columns', 'my_custom_reviews_column', 9999 );
function my_custom_reviews_column( $my_column ){
    $new_column = array(
        'custom' => 'Custom',
    );
    $my_column = array_slice( $my_column, 0, 3, true ) + $new_column + array_slice( $my_column, 3, NULL, true );
   return $my_column;
}
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_reviews_table_column_', 'my_custom_column_content', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
    if ( $column == 'custom' ) {
      echo 'test';
    }
}
```

I think the problem is the '**woocommerce_product_reviews_table_column_**'.

The code I wrote only displays the new column title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`woocommerce_product_reviews_table_column_` is invalid hook, you need to join `$column_name` as well in this hook at the end.

From the example, your column name is `custom` so the hook name will be `woocommerce_product_reviews_table_column_custom` and you don't need to `if ( $column == 'custom' )` inside the function.

You'll get `$item` param in action to use, which is the review/reply object. and if you have to get product ID using that object than you'll have to use `$item->comment_post_ID` to do that.

Here is your final code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_reviews_table_column_custom', 'my_custom_column_content' );
function my_custom_column_content( $item ){
    $product_id = $item->comment_post_ID;
    
    echo 'Product ID:' . $product_id;
}
```